# How to convert a web page into an image using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, uiimageview

This task is very hard to finish in other programming languages,

what about in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if Matlab is the best way to do this, but here's how:

1. use Matlab's built-in ***web*** function to open your webpage in a Matlab browser
2. Download and use the [ScreenCapture](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-screencapture) utility from the Matlab File Exchange to save a screenshot to file

If you need finer-grained control, you can use Java's [java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) to take a screenshot that you can then save. This can be done from within Matlab (it is actually the basis of the ScreenCapture utility), or from standalone Java code.

Comment: Can it work without actually start up the browser or just start it internally ?

Comment: No: to get a screenshot you need it to be visible

Answer (score 0):

you could install one of [these](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=screen+grab&cat=all) firefox plugins (along with firefox), make a system call to firefox from your program with the appropriate arguments to firefox, and voila, you have a program that takes screenshots of a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for a pure MATLAB solution.  But if you have Python handy, take a look at [PyWebShot](http://www.coderholic.com/pywebshot-generate-website-thumbnails-using-python/).  Then, you can just call the Python script from MATLAB using the [exclamation mark syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-12994.html#f0-38522), etc.

Comment: Which version of python does it require?Will it work with python 2.5?

Comment: It works with Python 2.5.  But also take note of the other dependencies in the blog post I linked to and make sure you install those as well.

Comment: I'm using windows XP,and I've managed to install python `gtk` package,but I can't get `gtkmozembed` package installed,there is no binary installer available anywhere:(

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do that in MATLAB (nor why would you want to do that in MATLAB, unless it's a part of something larger) ... but there is a specialized plugin for Firefox, for doing just that ... [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648/?src=api). Works nicely, no fussing about.